# Ubuntu 18.04 - Show Bluetooth connected device battery status

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, battery

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest update.
Can you tell me how can I find or get Bluetooth speaker battery level.?

As like If I connect the speaker to the iPhone it shows a connected device with battery level.

Comment: Did you click on the battery icon on top?

Comment: @Pilot6 It shows only laptop battery.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659/check-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-device-on-linux

Answer (score 4):

You can go to settings>Power and there you should see connected devices and their battery

Comment: I don't see that on Ubuntu 20.10.